# cpp file of character in unreal not showing in visual studio solution explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unreal-engine4

[image]I created a cpp file for a character class in unreal engine and I'm trying to edit the code in it. It opens up in visual studio but I cannot find it in the solution explorer page and vs does not suggest/ autofill syntaxes when I'm editing it.
I've tried restarting vs and UE and it did not work.

Comment: I've manually added the files into the solution explorer but it still doesn't show me context specific suggestions

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the C++ file is included in the Visual Studio project.
- Refresh the Visual Studio project.
- Ensure the Visual Studio Intellisense database is up to date.
- Rebuild the Visual Studio project.

Comment: I've manually added the files into the solution explorer but it still doesn't show me context specific suggestions

Answer (score 0):

its been 4 days but you can close Unreal and visual studio ,right click on .uproject file in your project folder then click generate visual studio project files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).